# Link library project to qt console/widget project with qt-creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, project

Using Qt-Creator, let's suppose I have this 2 projects:

- Library / C++ library
- Application / Qt Console Application

I want link the library project with the application project in a way that when I build the latter, the compiler knows how to find the *.a and *.dll (or *.so, if running qt-creator in linux) files in the other project. I also wat to be able to use the header from the library this way:

```
#include <lib_example_header>
```

and when building the project, the compiler also knows how to find the correct *.h file.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with qt creator You're asking about how to do it in qmake. You may wish to google those terms and see what comes up. Qt Creator is just a front-end that gives you a template for the qmake .pro file. It's up to you to go from there. Generally speaking, you'll want to have **one** project - a subdirs project, with the library and the application as two subprojects. But it'll still be messy with qmake. I suggest creating a `CMakeFile.txt` by hand, where it's pretty much trivial to link the library with the executable. Then open that file in Qt Creator :)

Comment: My question involve qt-creator because I wonder if somehow there is some way to make this "linking" with qt-creator settings, the ide could do all the compiler/linker task that involves the library automatically. I mean, having this 2 projects "linked", when compiling or linking the at console or widget project, the ide adds the related options to the compiler/linker based with the correct file locations baased on the project files it understands.

Comment: Absolutely not. Qt Creator does not handle anything related to the build process. It's an IDE. It lets the build tools handle the build, linking, etc.

Comment: The IDE needs no access to the compiler/linker options. All that the IDE does is initialize the project with your preferred compiler added to the path, and from that point onwards you're on your own. The IDE consumes the metadata from your chosen build tool (either qmake or cmake) to report the project structure. And it invokes the build tool and the debugger for you. And runs clang server to generate a code model. But it has no access to any options, nor would you want it to. We've already got that mess in Visual Studio, since time immemorial. It's best this misstep was forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

We'll do this using cmake, since that's what you should be using for any new project, and it's 10x easier to deal with than the requisite three (3!) project files for qmake. Not worth it. It's not a transferable skill, even.

Thus, let's say we'll have a `mylibrary` static library, that will be linked to `myexe` executable.

To get started, simply add the four files below to a folder (they are complete), and open the project in Qt Creator. Choose your preferred build kit (the combination of compiler and Qt build). Then press Ctrl-B (or ⌘-B on Mac), and wait for the build to finish. Then Ctrl-R / ⌘-R to run it. A message should appear.

From that point onwards, you'll want to read some cmake documentation to figure out what all the below means, especially the PRIVATE/INTERFACE/PUBLIC distinction.

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(test10 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

add_library(mylibrary STATIC
    lib.cpp
    lib.h
)
target_link_libraries(mylibrary PUBLIC Qt5::Core)
target_include_directories(mylibrary PUBLIC .)

add_executable(myexe
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(myexe PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets mylibrary)
```

The library provides a simple `getString()` function:

```
// lib.h
#pragma once
#include <QString>

namespace lib {
QString getString();
};
```

```
// lib.cpp
#include "lib.h"

namespace lib {
QString getString() {
   return QStringLiteral("Hello, world!");
}
}
```

The executable shows a message using that function:

```
// main.cpp
#include <lib.h>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Information", lib::getString());
}
```

This is probably the easiest way to achieve it. I won't even bother adding an equivalent qmake example: you'd need three `.pro` files, and there's no automatic way to link a subproject's output. CMake is the easy way here.

Comment: I try that option, create the CMakeLists.txt file and copy/paste the content above (only change the names `mylibrary` and `myexe` to the name of the projects I already had here, and file names for the library are example.cpp and example.h). When I open in the qt-creator, I get the screen Configure project, asking me to select a kit to be used - but none of the options are available to choose. Only option enabled is the "Import Existing Build..." which open a dialog to select on from disk.

Comment: @KleberMota Well, that's the problem, then. Qt Creator is just an IDE. It doesn't build anything by just itself. You have to install a build of Qt to use, as well as some compilers. This problem has nothing to do with  cmake nor this example project, although when attempting new things I suggest changing nothing. You can change the project names later, from within Qt Creator's editor (you'll be maintaining the CMakeLists.txt file there). Use the Qt Maintenance tool to download at least a basic mingw-based Qt version. That will include the gnu compiler tooling.